# iOS 8 - UILabel observer on change of text not being called

Tags: iphone, ios8, uilabel

I have a piece of code that runs perfectly until iOS 7, but now, with iOS 8 it does not work any more. 
I have a UILabel and I have a class that is set to observe any changes in its text. The setup is as below..

```
[lcdLabel addObserver:self
               forKeyPath:@"text"
                  options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew| NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld
                  context:NULL];
```

And this is how I am registering the changes.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
     //other code related to observation goes here
}
```

Any help as to why this stopped working (the `observeValueForKeyPath` method is not getting called any more) in iOS8?

Comment: From what method are you calling the addObserver method. Are you sure that lcdLabel has been created at that time?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I have implemented a very basic key value observing (KVO) example on a UILabel's text property and it works consistently on both iOS 7 & iOS 8. So you may just have something wrong your code that you are not showing.

That being said, I do not think that KVO is the best approach to responding to changes of the lcdLabel.text property.

Apple's KVO document specifically states:

**Note:** Although **the classes of the UIKit framework generally do not support KVO**, you can still implement it in the custom objects of your application, including custom views.

Also, the documentation for UILabel mentions nothing of KVO compliance for the text property. Therefore, I do not think that you should rely on this approach.

Unlike a UITextField, the text property of a UILabel, will never change without you specifically setting it, you can simply subclass UILabel and override the setText method.

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text {
    _text = text;
    // other code related to observation goes here
    // or call back to the UIViewController via a delegate through a custom protocol
}
```

You may also want to override setAttributedText as well.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem had here. I cannot change UILabel.text from delegate method. The method fires, but UILabel is not updated or screen refreshed...
I am using SWIFT... tried to implement NSNotification centre- the same problem...
Found out that I was calling delegate method from completion handler block and it was not able to update UIlabel as it has to be done on main thread.

Added:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

```
                ... update label...
            });
```

and worked like a charm